# MySQL: Database changed

Tags: mysql, spring

I'm following this Spring Tutorial: [Spring Tutorial Link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/spring-persistence-layer-writing.html)

I'm trying to use the MySQL command: use "DataBase Name" and I'm getting the response "Database changed.

```
mysql> use timesheet
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    8
Current database: *** NONE ***

Database changed
mysql> use timesheet
Database changed
```

What does 'use DBName' do?
Why am I getting the message of 'Database changed' ?

Comment: I guess MySQL documents explain it well http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "use" keyword defines which database you are currently writing SQL against.  You are getting the message 'Database Changed' as the database you are writing SQL against at that point has changed.

Further description available http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-use.html

Answer (score 3):

That's referring to the "active" database for your current connection.  Any queries run after the `use` statement will refer to objects in that database by default.

"Database changed" doesn't actually mean anything in the database itself has changed, only a reference in your connection.

Comment: aka "You have changed to a different database"

Answer (score 1):

You are "changing" databases to operate on. `use DBName` tell the database "everything I do now, I want to do to the DBName database".